# iPhone - How to change String in Label properly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I am currently learning to program on iPhone.

I currently have a small test app with a mock up keypad, so I have a few buttons that when pressed should place some text in a label.

I then take whats in the label and use it to open an ABUNKnownPersonControllerView for use there. Just a basic app to get used to a few things in the iPhone.

Where I am having trouble seems to be with working with the string used to display what I want in the label. I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error so I've re-read the memory management docs but I cant find anywhere that there should be a memory leak.

So I think my problem is I am incorrectly working with the String. My code is as follows:

//Header file

```
@interface KeyPadViewController : UIViewController <ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate>{
IBOutlet UILabel *phoneNumber;
//NSString *number;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *phoneNumber;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *number;

-(IBAction)addNum1;
-(IBAction)addNum2;
-(IBAction)showUnknownPersonViewController;
```

//Implementation file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Keypad",@"Keypad");
//self.number = @"";
self.phoneNumber.text = @"";
}


-(IBAction)addNum1{

//self.number = [self.number stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
self.phoneNumber.text = [self.phoneNumber.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];

}

-(IBAction)addNum2{

//self.number = [self.number stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
self.phoneNumber.text = [self.phoneNumber.text stringByAppendingString:@"2"];


}
```

And the showUnknownPerson view in the implementation file:

```
-(void)showUnknownPersonViewController
{
    //NSString *contactNum = self.phoneNumber.text;
    ABRecordRef aContact = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
    ABMultiValueRef email = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    bool didAdd = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(email, self.phoneNumber.text, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);

    if (didAdd == YES)
    {
        ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty, email, &anError);
        if (anError == NULL)
        {
            ABUnknownPersonViewController *picker = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
            picker.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
            picker.displayedPerson = aContact;
            picker.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
            picker.allowsActions = YES;


            [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
        }
        else 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                            message:@"Could not create unknown user" 
                                                           delegate:nil 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }   
    CFRelease(email);
    CFRelease(aContact);
}
```

And the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
[phoneNumber release]; //@synthesize
```

// [number release]; //@synthesize
    [super dealloc];
    }

I have tried using a Mutable string but have the same error, I've also tried not releasing the UILabel and the NSString and have the same issue.

When my app loads if I press one button and one character appears in the label, if I then use the showUnknowPersonViewController everything works fine, have if I press button 1 and then button 2 so that I know have two characters in the UILabel ("12") and select to use the showUnknownPersonViewcontroller then I get the crash.

```
*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1226a0
```

However I don't understand where it could be getting deallocated?

This is probably something basic I've missed in the tutorials but I cant figure it out, can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:** Just to add if the self.phoneNumber.text (UILabel) returns either empty or one character it works fine however if its 2 or more I get the crash.

---

**EDIT 2**: I have removed my NSString from the code completely and I still have the same issue, so it looks like its the UILabel thats causing the issue? See code changed above.

Comment: Don't you know the line of the crash appearance? Try to enable NSZombieEnabled, see if it gets you any further!

Comment: @Joetjah, I have added NSZombieEnabled to the debugger but I am using Xcode 4 and I cant seem to get it working to show me the line where it is crashing, when I run it, it always shoes me this line :   int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem may be in the line:

```
self.phoneNumber.text = number;
```

You are setting self.phoneNumber.text to the same string as number, not to a copy or to a newly created string with the same content.  Thus, in your addNum methods, the setter of one property releases the string when it resets its value.  The second property is still pointing to the released string.  When the setter of the second property is called, it tries to release that string again.  Hence, the error.

If this is the problem, it could be solved by rewriting the line as:

```
self.phoneNumber.text = @"";
```

Although, even this is probably not necessary.  All instance variables are initiated to nil, and it would not be necessary to give it an initial value.

Comment: Getting closer I think but I still have the same issue, I have removed the NSString from my code entirely and I changed the line above to what you recommended, I still have the same issue but it looks like it is my UILabel that is the issue for some reason? But I still cant get it to work!

Comment: Same problem in both addNum methods.  Try changing the second line to:  self.phoneNumber.text = [NSString stringWithString:self.number];

Comment: Again no joy doing it that way, with my code for the addNum function as this : self.number = [self.number stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
    self.phoneNumber.text = [NSString stringWithString:self.number]; I still get the same error.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your edits.  Code looks good to me.  I ran out of ideas.  Came back hoping you'd figured it out.  Maybe try to get NSZombie working on Xcode 4.  I can't help you there, I'm sticking with Xcode 3 for now.  (I take it you are hitting Build & Run and not just Run after you make the edits.  I know, very basic, but it's the sort of thing one might do when using a new editor.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your *NSString* variable *number* is causing the problem. It seems the values you assign to that variable are not retained anywhere. As you are using *self* to access the variable *phoneNumber*, you need use that for accessing the *number* too. Using *self* calls the setter for the particular property where the property is actually retained.

Comment: I have tried that just now but I still get the exact same issue I've afraid, I've edited my code above to show you what I've changed

Answer (score 1):

I believe the property might also need to be declared as an IBOutlet, and, if so, that could be causing the problem.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *phoneNumber;
```

Comment: Added that to the code just now but it made no difference, I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Makes sense, I think this is necessary, but if it was causing the error it should have crashed the first time the IBOutlet was accessed.  See below, another idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you never allocate number. What is the initial value of number?
To my mind, you should allocate a string in your viewDidLoad

Comment: I do that in viewDidLoad as follows : self.number = @"";